# Read Table in R with "=" starting cell

Tags: r, import

I'm trying to read a table in R. I allways used the command read.table(...), but today I found an error when trying to read a table with a cell starting with the "=" symbol.

It is something like:

```
chr7    79435791    a   7   ,,......    \ak.f9ka

chr7    79435792    a   7   C$......    =.;a#Kk

chr7    79435793    T   7   ........    GF-FGGB
```

I use:

```
read.table(files, sep="\t", comment.char="", header=FALSE, colClasses=c("character"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

but I get the error:
The line 2 does not have 6 elements, and I think it is because of the = symbol.

How can I read this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your error. I copied exactly your example in a .txt file, and I do not get the error you get.

By the way, with a simple `read.table()`statement it does not read correctly the last value in row 2 because of the comment character, which you can disable (see `?read.table`).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to somewhat reproduce the error which gave me some ideas - it could of course go horribly wrong as well :)

This should hopefully do the trick:

```
 files.data.frame <- read.table(textConnection(readLines(files)), sep="\t")
```

And of course, add the extra options to read.table as deemed necessary.